# How to implement nested interface method whose return type is Outer interface?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, interface

I have an OuterInterface that has nested InnerInterface. OuterInterface has method called `GetInnerInterfaceReference()`. Return type for this method is InnerInterface.

```
interface OuterInterface {

    interface InnerInterface {
        public void InnerInerfaceMethod();
    }

    public InnerInterface GetInnerInterfaceReference();
}
```

Now it is implemented in Example class. So, GetInnerInterfaceReference() method should return reference to InnerInterface type variable. How to achieve this?

```
class Example implements OuterInterface,OuterInterface.InnerInterface {

    public void InnerInerfaceMethod() {
        System.out.println("inner method called");
    }

    public InnerInterface GetInnerInterfaceReference() {
        //return 
    }
}
```

Once I get reference, then I can use following code to call method inside the InnerInterface

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.GetInnerInterfaceReference().InnerInerfaceMethod();
    }
}
```

I can get results simply by calling `ex.InnerInterfaceMethod();`

But, I got this query when I was going through WebDriver interface. This WebDriver has some static nested interfaces and some method declarations. Some of these methods return types are these nested interfaces. So I wonder how these methods are defined in the implemented classes like in ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
class Example implements OuterInterface,OuterInterface.InnerInterface {

    public void InnerInerfaceMethod() {
        System.out.println("inner method called");
    }

    public InnerInterface GetInnerInterfaceReference() {
        return this; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Like This:

```
public interface OuterIntf {
    public interface InnerIntf {
        public OuterIntf someInnerMethod();
    }

    public InnerIntf someOuterMethod();
}

public class Implementation implements OuterIntf, InnerIntf{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see practise.OuterIntf.InnerIntf#someInnerMethod()
     */
    @Override
    public OuterIntf someInnerMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see practise.OuterIntf#someOuterMethod()
     */
    @Override
    public InnerIntf someOuterMethod() {

        return this;
    }

}
```